# keyerror when running wurst library with brightway

Tags: python, brightway

I am testing the wurst library for Brightway but I am facing some keyerrors with multiple functions.

For example if I run :

```
import wurst as w

#act is a random activity from ecoinvent database
w.transformations.geo.copy_to_new_location(act,'CA-QC')
```

I get a key error message. *KeyError: 'exchanges'*.

I get the same error with simpler functions such as *reference product*. looking into the code I see it calls act['exchanges'] which is not defined as a key in my database. If I run:

```
act.as_dict().keys()
```

I get `dict_keys(['comment', 'classifications', 'activity type', 'activity', 'database', 'filename', 'location', 'name', 'parameters', 'authors', 'type', 'reference product', 'flow', 'unit', 'production amount', 'code'])`. But not `'exchanges'`.

I am using Brightway version 2.1.1 and wurst 0.1. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wurst and Brightway are different ecosystems - they can talk to each other but should be separately. In Wurst, you need to load data from a data source - Brightway is one of those sources - and then manipulate it. Passing in a Brightway object won't work, as the data format is completely different. See the introduction in the [Wurst examples](https://github.com/IndEcol/wurst-examples) and the Wurst [documentation](https://wurst.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: ok, I was confused because some of the search functions worked when operated in a conventional brightway database. I guess this means that with wurst is better to do big changes all at once.